# Drupal Views Argument block Theming

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-theming

I created a View Argument and saved it as a block. I wanted to theme the Row style output and hence created a "views-view-fields--product-content-box2--block-1.tpl.php" and input my div tags with my class names and then included print commands to print the node body and node title. I did this based on the useful video @ http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode23

My problem is that when the page containing the above view block is shown, the newly created "views-view-fields--product-content-box2--block-1.tpl.php" isnt being used. Instead the standard block.tpl.php is used.

I have emptied the cache to no avail.

Any ideas on how to get this working will be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you rescan template files in the Views UI?

Comment: yes, i tried that before. The Row Style Out turned bold on the new template file name, but it still isnt using the new tpl file. Does Views with arguments have a different way of themeing or is the procedure same as normal Views?

Answer (score 0):

The block.tpl.php file is used to theme the block as a whole, not the content within it.

To theme each row with a single tpl file, make sure your theme has a node.tpl.php file, set the view's row style to "node", and name your tpl node-view-product_content_box2.tpl.php.